Electron Wayland apps will cause Kwin_wayland crash on Kubuntu 24.10
I'm using Kubuntu 24.10 with KDE Plasma 6.1.5 on Wayland, but I force use Wayland on Electron, and the app will start, but after a while the kwin_wayland will crash. What should I do to solve this problem?
These are my Kwin error logs:
2024/11/21 下午11:13 kwin_wayland_wrapper kwin_scene_opengl: 0x2:  
GL_CONTEXT_LOST in context lost 
2024/11/21 下午11:13 kwin_wayland_wrapper Fcitx 5.1.10 -- Get Signal No.: 152024/11/21   
下午11:13 kwin_wayland_wrapper Date: try "date -d @1732202029" if you are using GNU date ***   
2024/11/21 下午11:13 kwin_wayland_wrapper I2024-11-21 23:13:49.378463    
xcbmodule.cpp:76] Disconnected from X11 Display :1
 


What happens if you try to run it on Xorg instead of Wayland? You can select  Xorg instead of Wayland as an option in the login screen when you log in.

Electron on XWayland running well,But my Graphic card is AMD Radeon 780M with Mesa3D 24.2.3 default as Ubuntu 24.10.I want to try the Native Wayland experience on Apps

2024/11/21 下午11:13 kwin_wayland_wrapper kwin_scene_opengl: 0x2: GL_CONTEXT_LOST in context lost
2024/11/21 下午11:13 kwin_wayland_wrapper Fcitx 5.1.10 -- Get Signal No.: 152024/11/21 下午11:13 kwin_wayland_wrapper Date: try "date -d @1732202029" if you are using GNU date ***
2024/11/21 下午11:13 kwin_wayland_wrapper I2024-11-21 23:13:49.378463 xcbmodule.cpp:76] Disconnected from X11 Display :1
These are my Kwin error log

When starting plasma Wayland with an NVIDIA series, kwin always crashes.
The nvidia modules isn't in the initramfs and I assume the kernel hack to disable simpledrm only responds to the kernel parameter anyway.
You may also can try to explicitly tell the system to use nvidia.
I think this link can help you:
https://pimylifeup.com/ubuntu-enable-wayland/

But my graphic card is AMD Radeon 780M with Mesa 24.2.3 driver as default on 24.10.And Electron Apps could open as wayland mode,but kwin will crash after a while
